# Simple case with regression not working (PyTorch)

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, regression

This simple PyTorch code from https://medium.com/@benjamin.phillips22/simple-regression-with-neural-networks-in-pytorch-313f06910379 doesn't find the regression expected on figure 2, from data on figure 1.
I tried several layers (nb & size), optimizer, loss, learning rate, epoch.. The result is only a flat horizontal line. As a newbie, I think I missed something.

Data:
[image: figure 1]

Approx. expected result:
[image: figure 2]

```
####
#code from https://medium.com/@benjamin.phillips22/simple-regression-with-neural-networks-in-pytorch-313f06910379
####

import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.utils.data as Data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import imageio
import pandas as pd

torch.manual_seed(1)    # reproducible

x=torch.from_numpy(pd.read_csv('./x.csv').to_numpy())
y=torch.from_numpy(pd.read_csv('./y.csv').to_numpy())
x=x.float()
y=y.float()

# torch can only train on Variable, so convert them to Variable
x, y = Variable(x), Variable(y)

# view data
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.scatter(x.data.numpy(), y.data.numpy(), color = "orange")
plt.title('regression')
plt.xlabel('x input')
plt.ylabel('y output')
plt.show()


net = torch.nn.Sequential(
 torch.nn.Linear(1,20),
 torch.nn.Sigmoid(),
 torch.nn.Linear(20,20),
 torch.nn.Sigmoid(),
 torch.nn.Linear(20,1),
)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()  # this is for regression mean squared loss

my_images = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))

# train the network
for t in range(500):
  
    prediction = net(x)     # input x and predict based on x

    loss = loss_func(prediction, y)     # must be (1. nn output, 2. target)

    optimizer.zero_grad()   # clear gradients for next train
    loss.backward()         # backpropagation, compute gradients
    optimizer.step()        # apply gradients
    
    # plot and show learning process
    plt.cla()
    ax.set_xlabel('x input',fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('y output',fontsize=12)
    ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
    ax.set_ylim(min(y),max(y))
    ax.scatter(x.data.numpy(), y.data.numpy(), color = "orange")
    ax.plot(x.data.numpy(), prediction.data.numpy(), 'g-', lw=3)
    ax.set_title('regression step='+str(t)+" loss="+str(loss.data.numpy()),fontsize=16)

    # Used to return the plot as an image array 
    # (https://ndres.me/post/matplotlib-animated-gifs-easily/)
    fig.canvas.draw()       # draw the canvas, cache the renderer
    image = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')
    image  = image.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

    my_images.append(image)
    print(str(t)+" "+str(loss.data.numpy()))
   
# save images as a gif    
imageio.mimsave('./result.gif', my_images, fps=10)
```

x.csv data: from 0 to 191, step 1

y.csv data:

```
0.316905
0.322015
0.332582
0.310465
0.250653
0.292722
0.297352
0.276525
0.308451
0.283465
0.276011
0.29934
0.307176
0.28573
0.248667
0.288614
0.249795
0.255556
0.258393
0.235972
0.225121
0.207828
0.190252
0.192881
0.204084
0.167646
0.155202
0.146516
0.162462
0.182906
0.160287
0.213769
0.186362
0.201151
0.186125
0.190625
0.146851
0.169204
0.207855
0.196557
0.208835
0.2244
0.206303
0.193485
0.185266
0.205616
0.229315
0.196254
0.219849
0.209988
0.197361
0.195402
0.210149
0.240754
0.210418
0.191776
0.189532
0.206153
0.165696
0.187938
0.157561
0.163148
0.19473
0.18966
0.162334
0.189277
0.166506
0.198193
0.157867
0.135192
0.152216
0.137521
0.142007
0.121252
0.136517
0.118812
0.126124
0.141713
0.13222
0.2032
0.156077
0.166526
0.167117
0.130817
0.167058
0.188566
0.178803
0.224779
0.217089
0.194542
0.199796
0.246194
0.249908
0.23034
0.204611
0.222958
0.24259
0.234767
0.278205
0.267297
0.275127
0.264059
0.25439
0.287421
0.267725
0.252964
0.256326
0.229031
0.276914
0.244985
0.273892
0.298103
0.256733
0.27219
0.301747
0.278291
0.274979
0.300091
0.310184
0.333836
0.297877
0.279405
0.278263
0.291442
0.278518
0.28268
0.321826
0.355584
0.315503
0.338342
0.39687
0.388692
0.353228
0.368169
0.328025
0.407137
0.38092
0.357814
0.362786
0.405149
0.354694
0.348222
0.295455
0.307671
0.290612
0.24626
0.229377
0.26535
0.217139
0.206268
0.230013
0.255796
0.27014
0.246626
0.224845
0.272181
0.201281
0.252555
0.270198
0.289443
0.243552
0.238465
0.207842
0.197373
0.238857
0.224703
0.259659
0.288809
0.24757
0.264744
0.250775
0.245659
0.193861
0.296178
0.234242
0.219704
0.264879
0.290614
0.296195
0.237291
0.208546
0.295197
0.272628
0.288054
0.293539
0.305374
0.328142
0.328574
0.307407
0.298107
0.315636
0.301924
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is easy: increase the number of layers, of nodes of the layers, and of epochs.
Example: layer1=400 nodes, layer2=200 nodes, layer3=100 nodes, layer4=50 nodes, epochs=1500